# Как убрать «прыжок» сайта при открытии инструментов разработчика?

Tags: html, css

[image: Без инструментов разработчика]

[image: С интрументами разработчика]

Как убрать «прыжок» сайта при открытии инструментов разработчика или клавиатуры на телефоне?

Comment: В настройке высоты height у вас указано значение в процентах от текущего размера области. Можно указывать в другой метрике, например, в пикселях или в vh (тут подробнее https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но задавать абсолютные размеры в моем случае - не вариант. Я знаю, что это происходит из-за того что я указал относительный размер 100%, но также я знаю, что даже не смотря на это можно эту проблема убрать. К примеру на Хабре высота задана 100%, но при этом подобного нет.

Comment: задайте min-height и все